# Confusion on Gaussian curvature computation

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, curvature

**Exercise**

I'm attempting to find the Gaussian curvature of the catenoid $M$ parametrized by
$$
f(u,v)=(a\cosh v\cos u,a\cosh v\sin u,a v).
$$
I've run through the typical computations of $E,F,G,e,f,g$ to get
$$
K(u,v)=\frac{eg-f^2}{EG-F^2}=-a^{-2}\text{sech}^4(v),
$$
which I believe to be right.

**Problem**

My problem is that before going through the computations described above, I attempted to find $K(u,v)$ by computing the actual differential of the Gauss map (so I could then take its determinant) as follows: I computed that the Gauss map $N$ is 
$$
N(u,v)=\frac{\big(\cos(u),\sin(u),-\sinh(v)\big)}{\cosh(v)}.
$$
This is a map from a subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ into the two-sphere $S^2$, so if $v\neq 0$, then $\sinh(v)\neq 0$ and the projection given by $\pi\,:\,(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y)$ is a local coordinate system for $S^2$. Then
$$
d\big((\pi\circ N)(u,v)\big)=\begin{pmatrix}-\tfrac{\sin u}{\cosh v} & -\frac{\cos u\sinh v}{\cosh^2 v}\\
\frac{\cos u}{\cosh v} & -\frac{\sin u\sinh v}{\cosh^2 v}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and hence
$$
\det\Big(d\big((\pi\circ N)(u,v)\big)\Big)=\frac{\sin^2 u\sinh v}{\cosh^3 v}+\frac{\cos u ^2\sinh v}{\cosh^3 v}=\frac{\sinh v}{\cosh^3v}
$$
should be the Gaussian curvature of the catenoid (since this should work for $v=0$ as well via continuity), but evidently it isn't (it doesn't even involve $a$).

**Questions**

Apparently I have a misunderstanding of how differentials work, which I would like cleared up if possible. So

1. Why doesn't this method work?
2. Is there any way to make this method work?
3. What is it exactly that I am misunderstanding in terms of differentials here? I thought that the differential of a map $F:M\to N$ between manifolds could be computed via taking the total derivative of the coordinate expression of $F$. Is this not the case?

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated. Hopefully a question of this sort hasn't been asked before, but I'm not sure how I'd even check, since its more of a "proof verification" type problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The determinant of the matrix of derivatives depends on the coordinate systems you use - to get the correct expression you need to account for this, either by using coordinates that are orthonormal at the point of interest (so that the determinant is really the area ratio) or by multiplying by the ratio of area elements dudv/dxdy.

Comment: Remember, that you have to interpret the derivative of the Gauss map as a linear map from $T_PM$  to $T_{N(P)}S^2 = T_P M$.